# SwiftUI project not providing code highlighting or code completion (autocomplete)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

My project builds and runs fine. Everything works as it should. No errors. No bugs. All good. The problem is I can't get code completion or code highlighting to work. Every time I try to do add anything, like a background color or padding (really simple stuff), the project starts indexing/processing files and it doesn't stop. My computer also starts running slow and I can hear the fan going berserk. The weird thing is the computer is fine otherwise. I have 80GB of free space. I just formatted it (because of this problem). I have 2 other projects that are bigger in size and code completion works fine on those. I've done everything, clearing derived data, archives, restarting Xcode, restarting project, messing with the file directory, i deleted everything and reinstalled Xcode, i restored my comp to factory settings.

If anyone has any advice, it would be much appreciated. I have no idea what to look for because the project builds and runs just fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions ...

1. Use the Activity Monitor app (in Utilities) to keep an eye on the cpu usage on your machine.  It sounds like you're hitting an Xcode problem where it gets into a hard spin-loop.  Activity monitor will show Xcode (or one of its helper tasks) taking 100% of your cpu when this happens.  Quit Xcode and/or reboot.
2. Make sure you've updated to the latest Xcode .. currently 12.4.
3. I have had Xcode not do the code-completion thing once ... and for me just quitting and restarting Xcode was enough to get it going again.
4. You can also try cleaning Xcode's temporary files with "Product" / "Clean Build Folder".
5. As a last resort, I'd delete the "Developer" directory in ~/Library and re-install.

Comment: All of this is pure guesswork. And wiping out the Developer directory is just silly.